# Principal component analysis on binary variables (i.e. 0 or 1)

Tags: pca, binary-data

Can I do principal component analysis when I have only dummy variables? Is it preferable to construct quantitative continuous variables (when possible) using the dummy variables and then run the pca on these newly constructed variables?

Comment: Technically, you *can* perform PCA on dummies (e.g. [Python gist](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/272a3b7ecdc9df5a6be4068fa9fd3967)), but you should consider whether that will help you answer your research question. (Multiple) correspondence analysis is a common alternative to PCA in such cases.

Comment: (Multiple) Correspondence Analysis can be seen as an analogue to PCA for categorical data. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_analysis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correspondence_analysis

Comment: I have updated [this Python gist](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/272a3b7ecdc9df5a6be4068fa9fd3967) to include a brief example of multiple correspondence analysis.